Firebase Cloud Functions. why is functions.auth.user() undefined?
index.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

// Existing helloWorld function
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase! ::: FUNCTIONS - " + JSON.stringify(functions));
});

// New function to log newly created user's UID
exports.logNewUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  functions.logger.info(`New user created with UID: ${user.uid}`, {structuredData: true});
});

package.json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^12.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^6.0.1",
   
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

System Settings
node --version
v20.17.0

npm --version
10.8.2

firebase --version
13.18.0

Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error

Functions info

FUNCTIONS - {"alerts":{"appDistribution":{"newTesterIosDeviceAlert":"appDistribution.newTesterIosDevice","inAppFeedbackAlert":"appDistribution.inAppFeedback"},"billing":{"planUpdateAlert":"billing.planUpdate","planAutomatedUpdateAlert":"billing.planAutomatedUpdate"},"crashlytics":{"newFatalIssueAlert":"crashlytics.newFatalIssue","newNonfatalIssueAlert":"crashlytics.newNonfatalIssue","regressionAlert":"crashlytics.regression","stabilityDigestAlert":"crashlytics.stabilityDigest","velocityAlert":"crashlytics.velocity","newAnrIssueAlert":"crashlytics.newAnrIssue"},"performance":{"thresholdAlert":"performance.threshold"},"eventType":"google.firebase.firebasealerts.alerts.v1.published"},"database":{"writtenEventType":"google.firebase.database.ref.v1.written","createdEventType":"google.firebase.database.ref.v1.created","updatedEventType":"google.firebase.database.ref.v1.updated","deletedEventType":"google.firebase.database.ref.v1.deleted"},"storage":{"archivedEvent":"google.cloud.storage.object.v1.archived","finalizedEvent":"google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized","deletedEvent":"google.cloud.storage.object.v1.deleted","metadataUpdatedEvent":"google.cloud.storage.object.v1.metadataUpdated"},"https":{},"identity":{},"pubsub":{},"logger":{},"tasks":{},"eventarc":{},"scheduler":{},"remoteConfig":{"eventType":"google.firebase.remoteconfig.remoteConfig.v1.updated"},"testLab":{"eventType":"google.firebase.testlab.testMatrix.v1.completed"},"firestore":{"writtenEventType":"google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.written","createdEventType":"google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.created","updatedEventType":"google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.updated","deletedEventType":"google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.deleted","writtenEventWithAuthContextType":"google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.written.withAuthContext","createdEventWithAuthContextType":"google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.created.withAuthContext","updatedEventWithAuthContextType":"google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.updated.withAuthContext","deletedEventWithAuthContextType":"google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.deleted.withAuthContext"},"params":{"BUCKET_PICKER":{"resource":{"type":"storage.googleapis.com/Bucket"}},"declaredParams":[],"databaseURL":"params.DATABASE_URL","projectID":"params.PROJECT_ID","gcloudProject":"params.GCLOUD_PROJECT","storageBucket":"params.STORAGE_BUCKET"},"app":{}}

Why is auth undefined in functions.auth.user()?
I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling npm, node, and Firebase cli.
I've changed the function from v1 to v2 (I prefer using v1 for now).
I've rerun Firebase init and reinitialized the entire project.
I'm expecting the the functions to deploy.

According to the note at the top of the documentation, there is no v2 version of the the auth triggers.  I'm not clear what you mean when you said you switch to v2 - that shouldn't be possible.

@DougStevenson you're correct and I've discovered that ugprading "firebase-functions": "^51.1" to "firebase-functions": "^6.0.1" has caused functions.auth.users() to become undefined. Any idea why this is and how to fix the issue?

You could file an issue on GitHub and use the feedback button at the top of the page of documentation.

@DougStevenson Thanks for the feedback and I'll get right on it.

I changed 'firebase-functions' in my package.json file in my function folder from v6.0.1 to
  "dependencies": {
"firebase-admin": "^11.11.1",
"firebase-functions": "^5.1.1"

},
Note I think 'firebase-admin' and 'firebase-functions' both need to correlate as some versions of each aren't compatible with each other. Try changing both if you have problems...
That didnt fix it tho, I had to reinstall the dependencies by running..
cd functions //Your functions directory

and then
npm install firebase-functions firebase-admin

This fixed the issue
Thank you for this post. GPTS couldn't fix this and this is the only post I found about this issue. I would still be going around in circles if I didn't find this.
